# Image hover and transform issue

Tags: css

Two images each 50% width. I want to hover on the left image and it should widen to 52% over the right image. The right image should not move. Hover the right image and it should widen to 52% over the left image and the left image should not move.

Two issues...
1. The hover over the left image works but moving off it, it doesn't transform gracefully back to 50% but instead, it jumps back as if no transition effect is applied.
2. hovering the right image moves the right image to the left instead of expanding it.

CSS is shown here and I can't seem to identify what part(s) is/are incorrect so I am asking for help.

```
            <style>
body{
box-content: border-box;
}
.photo_section_new {
  display:flex;
}
.photo_section_new > div {
  height:800px;
  flex-grow:1;
  transition:0.5s;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.photo_section_new > div:nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #c54985;
  border-top: 20px solid #c54985;
  background:#000 url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/600/600);
  background-size: cover;

}


.photo_section_new > div:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #005d99;
  border-top: 20px solid #005d99;
  background:#000 url(https://picsum.photos/id/103/600/600);
  background-size: cover;

}

.photo_section_new > div:nth-child(3) { 
  display:none;
}

.photo_section_new > div:hover {
  flex-grow:1.1;
}
</style>


  <div class='photo_section_new'>
    <div id='main_photo'>
    </div>
    <div id='second_photo'>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
```

Neither image should move/change position.  They should each just expand over the other when they are hovered over. I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: I've updated the css. Left image hovering is working now.  I am asking for help with how to make the right image expand instead of moving to the left when hovered over.

Comment: I removed z-indexes and added another transition effect to #main_photo:hover + #second_photo. Seems to work as I would like but, is it normal for the images to shudder very slightly, during a transition?  New CSS posted in case it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating a simple task. Here is an easier idea using flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}
.container > div {
  height:200px;
  border-bottom:5px solid;
  flex-grow:1;
  transition:0.5s;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}

.container > div:first-child {
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/600/600)
}
.container > div:last-child {
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/103/600/600)
}

.container > div:hover {
  flex-grow:1.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It does almost as I would like except that the two images occupy just one third of the screen width each.  This means there's a gap of 1/3 in the middle.  I guess it's caused by flexbox which I shall read up on.

Comment: @headache what browser are you using? both image should fill all the width available

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu. I will check FF on ubuntu and chrome/ff/ie/edge on win 10 later today and advise.

Comment: Also Chrome on win10, FF on win 10 and FF on ubuntu.  All showing the same - the two images each occupy 1/3 of screen width (all sizes of screen) and the middle third is empty.  The hover expansion works as hoped for and it's only the gap between the images that is baffling me.  The images should meet centre-screen and occupy full height of the screen height in the media query  (min-width: 768px). On smaller screens, they need to be full width of the screen and shown one beneath the other.

Comment: Also IE on win 10.  Sidenote...why does the site give me the option to edit and display a link to enable me to do so but then, after making the edit, it flags up that I can only edit for five minutes.  I started to try my edit 21 mins afterwards, not as though I started within 5 but completed after 5 mins :\

Comment: Hmm, it seems 'flex' adds an empty div?  I have adjusted the css in the OP and have added the third child selector, assigning it display:none.  The first and second children cover the screen 50/50, more or less just as I want.  If I add similar attributes for the third child - without adding another html div - then three images cover the screen 33.3% each.  It appears that, so long as the number of html divs is one less than the number of images to be displayed and one child is assigned display:none, all will be well whether showing 1,2, 3 or 4 images side by side with no gaps.

Comment: @headache so you aren't talking about *my* code then? you seems to describe a complete different code and you are probably doing things wrong ... in the snippet here, do you see 2 images side by side growing on hover?

Comment: Yes they expand but that's not the issue. There was a 1/3 gap in the centre of the screen and I need both photos to be 50:50 of the whole screen. I added default CSS for child divs and saw the default photo as well as the proper two despite there being just 2 html divs - hence my notion of an invisible div. I adjusted part of the CSS to be nth-child(1), nth-child(2) and nth-child(3).  It displayed as it arrived from you i.e. with a 1/3 gap in the centre. I added display:none to the nth-child(3) and it's perfect. the gap is gone. Thank you. You assistance helped greatly.

Comment: @headache before tell me what you see in the snippet? you are describing something I don't see ... when you run the snippet here in my answer what do you see? is there a gap here in my code?

Comment: Yes, there's a gap on the screen.  One photo to the left, one to the right and a gap in the centre.  All equally proportioned.

Comment: @headache in **my** code? are you sure? can you show me a screenshoot of you running my snippet *here*, not outside or with your code

Comment: Interesting.  Your code, which I copied today, works as hoped for.  :)  I'm pleased however that it didn't display totally yesterday because it helped me along the road and it made me learn more. I don't agree with the concept of asking for help and being given plug 'n' play code.  Not fair on the helper and I want to learn and not plagiarise. :)   There are other things I need to do in those divs so it'll be interesting to see how I progress. As said, Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @headache it's not about to plagiarise but you were asking me to help with another code that I don't see, you were describing something else and this will not happen with my code so for sure you updated the code to something else. In this case I cannot help you since I don't know what you did that's why I insisted to see if you are talking about *my* code or another one.